# Как реализовать рандом с условием?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть рандом который видает цифры `0` или `1`.
Нужно между `0 и 1` добавлять блок `Angle_Left`, а между `1 и 0` `Angle_Top` как сделать?

```
var Random = new Random();

for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
float rand = Random.Next(0,2);

if(rand == 0){
 Console.WriteLine(rand + " — " + "Left");
}
if(rand == 1){
 Console.WriteLine(rand + " — " + "Top");
}
```

Пример:

```
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
1 - Top
1 - Top
  - Angle_Top
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
  - Angle_Top
0 - Left
0 - Left
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
1 - Top
```

Comment: Держи в памяти текущее значение Rand и предыдущее. Перед тем, как рисовать значение на основании текущего Rand, проверяй предыдущий и на основании этого пиши промежуточное сообщение.

Comment: можете показать на примере кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например:

```
Random r = new Random();
IEnumerable<int> GetRandomSequence()
{
    while (true)
        yield return r.Next(2);
}

IEnumerable<string> InsertCorners(IEnumerable<int> seq)
{
    int prev = -1;
    foreach (var curr in seq)
    {
        if (prev == 0 && curr == 1)
            yield return "  - Angle_Left";
        else if (prev == 1 && curr == 0)
            yield return "  - Angle_Top";

        if (curr == 0)
            yield return "0 - Left";
        else if (curr == 1)
            yield return "1 - Top";
        prev = curr;
    }
}
```

Тестируем:

```
foreach (var s in InsertCorners(GetRandomSequence().Take(20)))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

выдаёт

```
0 - Left
0 - Left
0 - Left
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
1 - Top
1 - Top
  - Angle_Top
0 - Left
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
1 - Top
  - Angle_Top
0 - Left
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
1 - Top
1 - Top
  - Angle_Top
0 - Left
0 - Left
0 - Left
  - Angle_Left
1 - Top
```

Comment: то что надо, спасибо большое)) 
а если ещё сделать чтобы в самом начале `Angle_Left` или`Angle_Top` или `Left` или `Top` ?

Comment: @KillNoise: Не совсем понял — что именно из четырёх?

Comment: первая строка в результате может быть `0 - Left` или `1 - Top` да ? можно ее ещё рандомить типа на `Angle_Left` или `Angle_Top` Но только первую строку

Comment: @KillNoise: Первая строка рандомная, 0 или 1.

Comment: @KillNoise: Вы можете вместо `int prev = -1;` сделать `int prev = r.Next(2);`, если хотите. Это добавит возможный угол.

Comment: Тогда будет не совсем верно  `- Angle_Left`
 `1 - Top` - значит ещё нужно между ними `Angle_Top` потому что следующий `1 - Top`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75114/discussion-between-kill-noise-and-vladd).

Comment: написал вам в чате